# Error 500 post angularjs jersey

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, jersey

This is the problem

[image: This is the error]

Here is the code which call the jersey part :

```
$http.post('/easyshow/api/shows/add', selectedShows).then(
function(data) {
    alert("Yes");
},
function(data, status, headers, config, statusText) {
    alert("No");
    console.log("data : " + data + "status : " + status + "headers : " + headers +
        "config : " + config + "statusText : " + statusText);
});
```

And finally the jersey method :

```
@POST
@javax.ws.rs.Path("/add")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response addShows(List<ScannedShow> body) {
    ...
    Response res = Response.status(Response.Status.OK) // 200
            .build();

    return res;
}
```

There is no error serverside. Everythings works, the objects are created and stored. But there is always this error 500 so I never go to the success case of the then...

Comment: you have an error in server side code please check..

Comment: no, i run debug on every single line and nothing unexpected happened. I think the problem could be in the angular code

Comment: manually hit this and check /easyshow/api/shows/add

Comment: There was an uncatched error, that's why my status 200 was never returned -_-. Thx buddy !!